# Android: How to view app logs in real devices like emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

I used to obtain app logs in Genymotion VMs using Android Studio. It shows all user and system apps in the dropdown menu.

For some reasons I have to use a real device to test a production app. However, The Logcat and Profiler tab in Android Studio always show "No debuggable processes".

Is there anyway to view logs in a real device in a way like that in Genymotion VMs, using any tools?

My device is in Android 7.1.1, with Magisk rooted and adbd Insecure working.

Comment: It seems that you use release build. Only debug build allows you to see logs from debugger

Comment: Yes but I tried the apps I tested before. It's fine for those on Genymotion VM but no on real device.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [android-log-collector](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-log-collector)

Download and install it, then connect device with PC, and run

```
adb shell logcat > log.txt
```

Comment: Is there any difference if I run it without installing android-log-collector?